# Can Firebase admin SDK retrieve user auth tokens?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

The firebase javascript client SDK has sustained access to, say, a facebook oauth token. My understanding is an app can just call `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential()` and if it is signed in, it will receive a facebook access token with which it can do API calls. The key point here is that the token is *not* stored in my database, but in firebase auth, securely.

I want my back-end to be able to make these API calls on behalf of my app. why can't I call `admin.auth.facebookauthprovider.credential()` to retrieve the token?

Please note I will actually be implementing this for Slack oauth. At the moment, I will otherwise have to encrypt Slack tokens in my firestore DB. This [instagram firebase](https://github.com/firebase/custom-auth-samples/blob/master/instagram/app.js) example does that, and I feel it defeats the purpose of firebase auth

Comment: Admin SDK operates as a special "admin" user. Individual end-user credentials are not available in that context. Although you can pass a Firebase ID token from a client app to the server, [verify it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and then perform some operation based on the result.

Comment: I also wanted to add that Firebase Auth does not store or manage any non-Firebase OAuth tokens. It only returns the initial OAuth tokens provided by IdP and discards them after.

Comment: oh... @bojeil I guess I misunderstood. Wouldn't it be a good feature if it did? Then authentication would be great - no encryption for firebase customers to deal with. I'm sure many would want to keep those original oauth tokens

Comment: You should file a feature request for it: https://firebase.google.com/support/